# Algorithm to Rank "Risk Factors" on Individual Level from Logit Regression Scoring

Tags: algorithms, logit, ranking, risk

I have a logit regression which predicts the probability of attrition.

The equation is roughly:
$$\log(\text{odds})=\text{logit}(P)=\ln(\frac{P}{1-P})=a+bX=\beta_0+\beta_{1...n}X_{1...n}+\delta_{1..n}Z_{1...n}+\epsilon$$

where

- beta naught (zero) is the intercept
- beta 1 to n and X 1 to n represent n continuous predictors of attrition
- delta 1 to n and Z 1 to n represent n dichotomous predictors of attrition
- epsilon is the error term

I fit the model on a large sample of individuals from my database. I use the fitted model to score new groups of individuals, rank them, then within each individual I apply an algorithm to identify the top 2 "risk factors" for each individual.

Risk factors are predictors in X, Z which contribute most highly to the individual's risk of attrition.

The algorithm I've been using is roughly:

1. Take the difference between the value of a predictor (a given X or Z) for an individual
2. Subtract the mean of the group from the individuals value, i.e. for an individual *i*, group *g*, and predictor X*n*, I have a difference = X*ni* - X*ng* = X*dni*

   - I'm sure I could notate this better, forgive me
3. Multiply the difference (X*dni*) with the coefficient of that predictor, i.e. X*dni* * B*n* = R*ni*
4. Rank all of the values from #3 within each individual for each predictor (X *1...n*, Z *1...n*), so if we have 10 X's and 10 Z's, then there are 20 ranked values R*ni* for each individual
5. Select the top 2 values from #4 (i.e. top 2 of R*i*) for each individual as their top risk factors

then launch a campaign to discuss the top 2 risk factors for each individual with them, in hopes of reducing their probability of attrition.

*Example*:

- B*n*  = -.1, i.e. it reduces probability of attrition (P) and thus is a "good" thing
- X*ni* = .5
- X*ng* = .4

Thus this individual has a higher value on a "good thing", which is good, and thus she is better than average on this predictor of attrition.

.5 - .4 = .1
.1 * -.1 = -.01

On the other hand, if  X*ni* = .5, X*ng* = .4, but B*n*  = .1, then the individual is worse than average (because the sign of B is positive) and R*ni* = .01.

This seems reasonable, because the risk factor where the individual is better than average is ranked -.01, which is lower than the one where they are worse than average (R*ni* = .01), thus if we were only picking 1 of this 2 values as a "risk factor" we'd correctly select the higher ranking (.01) factor where they are worse than average. We scale this up to include all X and Z, 1...n.

**My question is basically "is this a valid approach or is there a way to improve the algorithm?"**

A problem I've been having seems to revolve around the binary predictors Z, though theoretically it could probably occur with the continuous predictors X as well. Here's what happens:

- A person is above average ("good") on the values of X,
- there's a Z*n* which reduces the probability of attrition slightly, i.e. Dn = -.002
- the value of Z*ni* = 1, which is "good" for individual i and reduces their probability of attrition, i.e. 1 - X*ng* = 1 - .3 = .7 and .7 * -.002 = -.0014
- however, R*ni* = -.0014 is still selected as a top risk factor even though reduces P, because the other values of R for individual i are bigger reducers of risk

*Example*:

- If X's are things like age, income, and time spent reading, and
- Z*n* is an indicator for if an individual has a PhD

then intuitively, having a PhD should not be considered a risk factor for individuals who have PhD's, but if the person is sufficiently above average on the factors in X, then having a PhD may reduce the probability of attrition the least (or 2nd to least, since we select 2 risk factors) and thus it gets reported as a risk factor even though that doesn't seem to make much real-world sense.

Currently, I've "patched" the algorithm in my `R` code using conditional statements that say things (in the code's language) like "if a person has a PhD and PhD is ranked in the top 2 then delete it". However, I wonder if there's a fundamentally better approach to the algorithm, so that I change the model specification in the future then I don't have to worry about catching these weird cases.

**Are these types of problems fundamentally a scaling issue? Is this problem limited to dichotomous variables? What's a better approach?**

Thanks in advance; I know it's a long question.

Comment: @user777 thanks. I actually was using LATEX in the image you replaced, but I downloaded it as a .gif from this LATEX editor -- http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php  -- because I couldn't get the install to work too well on my Windows desktop and I'm not very experienced with it. I don't think that you introduced any errors. Looks good; appreciate your help. I have to work on another project this second, but I will try to come back and add more LATEX.

Comment: @user777 That's completely understandable. Does it need to be raw LATEX code of some sort or is it okay to use images from that editor / web app I found? Do you have any recommendation for an easy way to do LATEX in Windows? I use Notepad++ and Microsoft Office.

Comment: @user777 Great. I'll definitely fix this up today. Thanks again!

Comment: Just discovered http://www.mathjax.org/ from the help pages while trying to follow your LATEX code =) . This question is about ranking algorithms but the value in this post may end up being a lesson in LATEX lol